# Greatest Common Divisor parking meter problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

A parking meter can hold $k$ quarters, $2k$ nickels, and $4k$ dimes.  Find all $k$ such that the total when the meter is full is a whole number of dollars.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't know where to start

Comment: For those not based in the US these coins are 0.25 dollars, 0.05 dollars and 0.10 dollars respectively.

Comment: Hint: What is the total as an expression in $k$?

Comment: A quarter is of a different value from a nickel. The value of all the quarters is $0.25k$. Can you do the same for the other 2 denominations?

Comment: @Element118 Ok so $t = .25k + 2(.05k) + 4(.10k)$?

Comment: Hint: can you simplify this? What if it is a whole number of dollars?

Comment: @Element118 $t = .75k$?

Comment: When can it be an integer?

Comment: @Element118 So when $k$ is a multiple of 4, there's a multiple of a dollar in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start off by writing the total value as an expression in $k$:

$$t=0.25k+2(0.05)k+4(0.10)k$$

Simplifying gives:

$$t=0.75k=\frac{3k}{4}$$

Hence, for $t$ to be an integer, $4\mid3k$. As $\gcd(3, 4)=1$, this is equivalent to $4\mid k$.

You can check that all these solutions work as we can let $k=4l$:

$$t=0.75(4l)=3l\in\mathbb{N_0}$$

Answer (score 0):

How much money is in the meter if $k=1$?  What is the smallest number you can multiply that by to get a whole number of dollars?